# Generate content format for mult items within view

Tags: views

**What I'm trying to do**

Create a View that looks similar to this, but with multiple titles, each which represents a "Team":
[image]

So you can imagine a page where multiple teams are listed, each with a `Title` and a `Description` and an image for each team member (which links to their profile).

**How would you accomplish this?**

**What I've thought to do so far**
So far, I thought that I could create a Content Type with these fields:

- Title
- Description
- Image (unlimited)
- Name (unlimited)
- Link (unlimited)

Then I thought I could create a View and use custom text, but that didn't work because it renders per field (if that makes sense).  So, if I put `<a href='[field_url]'>[field_image]</a>`, it prints out `<a href='url1,url2'>img1,img2</a>`.

I assume there's a way to do this that I'm just not thinking of.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is multiple 'rows' for team members. to accomplish this with your configuration you could uncheck **Display all values in the same row** for your image, name and link field.

[image]

It is better to use a module for your grouped fields like [paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) module.